# Acceptance-Reject to generate a distribution proportionate to Inverse Gamma and truncate Cauchy distribution

Tags: bayesian, simulation, accept-reject

Assume $Y_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$, $\mu_i \sim N(\eta,\tau^2)$ for $i=1,2$ $j=1,\cdots,n_i$ and prior $\pi(\eta,\tau^2,\sigma^2) \propto Ca^+(\tau^2,0,b_{\tau}) \times Ca^+(\sigma^2,0,b_{\sigma})$
where $Ca^+(x; 0, b)$ is the truncated Cauchy distribution with pdf $$f(x|b)=\frac{2}{\pi}\times \frac{1}{b[1+(x/b)^2]}I_{[x>0]}, b>0$$
[image: full]

I want to use JAGS with R to do Bayesain analysis. Because the full conditionals for $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are not a known density, I want to use Acceptance-Reject sampling with $\tau^* \sim IG(a,b)$, $C_{max}=Ca^+(0;0,b_{\tau})$ and the acceptance probability is $\frac{Ca^+(\tau^*;0,b_{\tau})}{C_{max}}$.
$IG(x;a,b)$ the inverted Gamma distribution with pdf $$f(x|a,b)=\frac{b^a e^{-b/x}x^{-(a+1)}}{\Gamma(a)}$$
How do I use Acceptance-Reject sampling when I don't have the complete form of the density function?

Comment: It is not useful to repost a question while not accounting for the earlier remarks. All conditional densities in the question have closed form expressions, up to a constant. And please avoid pictures of equations for readability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

When simulating $\zeta=\tau^2$ from
$$p(\zeta)\propto IG(\zeta;0,(\mu_1-\eta)^2/2+(\mu_2-\eta)^2/2)\times Ca^+(0,b_ \tau)$$
using a proposal $$p(\zeta)\propto IG(\zeta;a,b)$$
the acceptance ratio is
$$\dfrac{IG(\zeta;0,(\mu_1-\eta)^2/2+(\mu_2-\eta)^2/2)\times Ca^+(0,b_ \tau)}{M\times IG(\zeta;a,b)}$$
i.e.,
$$\dfrac{\zeta^{-1}\exp[-(\mu_1-\eta)^2/2(\mu_1-\eta)^2/2+(\mu_2-\eta)^2/2\zeta+(\mu_2-\eta)^2/2\zeta]}{M[1+\zeta^2/b^2_\tau]\,\zeta^{-1-a}\,\exp[-b/\zeta]}$$
where $M$ is the maximum of the ratio (if it exists). Assuming the tails of $IG(\zeta;a,b)$ are fatter than those of the numerator, the accept-reject method thus applies once $M$ is constructed.

Comment: Is $M$ the  acceptance probability $\frac{Ca^+(\tau^*;0,b_{\tau})}{C_{max}}$ ($C_{max}=Ca^+(0;0,b_{\tau})$ )?

Comment: The acceptance probability is the one I gave.